# What lilo option should I use to set a script to run when my linux system reboots?

Tags: linux, boot

I want to set a script to run when my Linux system reboots. What lilo option should I use?

```
lilo -R
lilo -S
lilo -T
lilo -L
```

Please suggest.

Comment: The clean way to do that is to use the operating system features, not some boot loader trick. Take a look at System V init, and /etc/rc*

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the flavour of the OS, but chances are that if you look into /etc/rc.local you find:

> This script is executed at the end [of the boot] ... by default this script does nothing

so you can write commands directly into this file (ensure it is executable) or call from there any script you can put where you want.

EDIT: I said this already in a comment above but, for completeness, it is better to say it again here. The ability to start a user defined script or command is a basic feature of a good operating system - even DOS (and earlier OSes) had it. Instead, boot loaders are meant to *load* an os, not to fiddle with it. While LILO and other bootloaders can in some way interact with the system (kernel) being loaded, this capability is to be used to solve hardware or similar problems, not to override the OS way to do things.